# ASP.NET MVC: Коллекция в модели, как заполнять?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mvc

Помогите разобраться. Сгенерировал crud контроллер. В модели у меня находится коллекция, так вот хочу, чтобы на странице создания по кнопке добавлялись поля ввода для элементов этой коллекции.

Пытался делать по гайду http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Сейчас вместо добавления поля ввода кидает на отдельную страницу с этим полем ввода

**Checklist.cs** - моя модель

```
public class Checklist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Checks> CheckList { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Checks
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Check { get; set; }
}
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4 align="right">New Checklist</h4>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Identifier, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "15", @style = "width:280px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Identifier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "255" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    <table id="Table">
        <tr>
            <th>Checks</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="editorRows">
                @if (Model.CheckList != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.CheckList)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_create_check", item);
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    @Html.ActionLink("Add", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
```

**add-check.js**

```
$('#addItem').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**_create_check** - частичное представление

```
@model MyProject.Models.Checks

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("checks")) { 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Check, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

**ChecklistsController.cs**

```
public ViewResult BlankEditorRow()
{
    return View("_create_check", new Checks());
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    Checklist checks = new Checklist();
    return View(checks);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Identifier,Title,Date,CheckList")] Checklist checklist)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        checklist.Date = DateTime.Now;
        db.Checklists.Add(checklist);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(checklist);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вам посоветовал сделать отображение `PartialView` по кнопке и его скрытие по другой кнопке. Приведу пример:

```
<div id="partialBlankEditor" style="display : none;">
   @Html.Partial("BlankEditorRow", Model.LiftItems.Where(x => x.IsDeleted).ToList())
</div>
```

Так как метод `BlankEditorRow` возвращает частичное представление, то у нас после загрузки страницы сразу отобразится частичное представление. Для скрытия и отображения можно использовать у `div` свойство `display: none;`, на основное представление добавить кнопку по нажатию на которую будем у `partialBlankEditor` менять свой свойство на `display: block;` к примеру. Вот таким кодом:

```
$('#partialBlankEditor').style.display = 'block';
```

Навесим это к примеру на кнопку вместо этого:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })
```

сделаем просто кнопку с идентификатором:

```
<button type="button" id="btn-show-editor">Show add</button>
```

Ну и обработка будет такой:

```
$('#btn-show-editor').click(function () {
    $('#partialBlankEditor').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Ну а в на частичном представлении нужно будет тоже кнопку добавить, по нажатию на которую будем добавлять значение.

```
@model MyProject.Models.Checks

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("checks")) { 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Check, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <button type="button" id="btn-add-new-item">Add new</button>
}
```

Обработку нажатия кнопки сделаем тоже простой, скрываем частичное представление и вызываем метод Ajax:

```
$('#btn-add-new-item').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'CreateNew',
        cache: false,
        data: {id: '@Model.Id', check: '@Model.Check'}
        success: function (response) { 
          // $("#editorRows").append(response); немного иначе нужно сделать перерисовку
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Нужно написать новый метод, с помощью которого будем добавлять новое значение и возвращать новый список, причем нужно будет отправить данные в `Data` с помощью `Ajax` из `@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("checks"))`. Я не пользовался `BeginCollectionItem`, поэтому посоветую старый добрый `@using(Ajax.BeginForm` позволяющий обновить часть страницы без перезагрузки ее целиком.

Новый метод как-то так будет выглядеть:

```
// имена должны совпасть с данными из Ajax 
public ActionResult CreateNew(int id, string check)
{
    Checks newData = new Checks() { Id = id, Check = check };
    // куда-то добавляем наш чек, в БД к примеру
    // получаем идентификатор, так как он будет нулевым, так как объект новый
    // newLst - это новый набор данных из IEnumerable<Checks>
    // можно сериализовать через JavaScriptSerializer newLst
    return Json(newLst);
}
```

Вот этот блок кода вызывает вопросы и сомнения:

```
<td id="editorRows">
    @if (Model.CheckList != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.CheckList)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_create_check", item);
        }
    }
</td>
```

Вот он немного не ясен, возможно Вы тут хотели что-то отобразить в виде списка к примеру? Но тут наверняка не нужно отображать частичное представление добавления новых. Во-первых, у вас в модели `CheckList` будет пустой коллекцией и не отобразится ни одного элемента. В общем, перепишите этот блок кода, то что находится внутри цикла `foreach`, чтобы потом аяксом можно было обновить список, к примеру сделать через `select` и `option`, его будет просто перерисовать через Ajax